# How to get byte stream of specified seconds for wav file on android?

Tags: android, audio, inputstream, wav

Is there any way to get audio stream from a wav file (wav file in particular) in android?

I am trying to get the stream of a particular interval(i.e from startTime to endTime where startTime is not zero). For example, to get the audio stream from 5 sec to 10 sec (5 sec duration) of a 20 sec long wav file.

How to do that? 
I see this link but this is for java not android and you know javax not supported for android.
[Get byte stream from an audio file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996526/get-byte-stream-from-an-audio-file)

Comment: you want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372813/android-audiotrack-playing-wav-file-getting-only-white-noise and probably the setLoopPoint of tha AudioTrack class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#setLoopPoints(int, int, int)

Comment: @pna hi.I see this link.But it was just about playing wav.I dont want record or play waves.i have already wav file and want an audio stream from one specified seccond to other.can you help me more?

Comment: and @pna I read refrenced for develope android about SetLoopPoint.But I didnt undertnand the work of this method.looping for an audio what s mean?can u help me?